# WPF: How do I validate that a number from memory is not duplicated in db table?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq, entity-framework

I'm having trouble figuring out how to determine if a number is duplicated.

Right now, the process is when the user clicks on a button to browse for an xml file, the xml file gets deserialized and stored into db and the data gets shown on a DataGrid on the view.

So, I added a confirmation dialog so when the user clicks on browse, the code checks to see if the lot_number being deserialized is a duplicate or not from inside a column from a table in database. I only want the user to be able to add lot numbers to db that are not duplicates.

Here's my code so far:

```
public void DeSerializationStream(string filePath)
    {
        XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
        xRoot.ElementName = "lot_information";
        xRoot.IsNullable = false;

        // Create an instance of lotinformation class.
        var lot = new LotInformation();

        // Create an instance of stream writer.
        TextReader txtReader = new StreamReader(filePath);

        // Create and instance of XmlSerializer class.
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LotInformation), xRoot);

        // DeSerialize from the StreamReader
        lot = (LotInformation)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(txtReader);

        // Close the stream reader
        txtReader.Close();

      }

public void ReadLot(LotInformation lot)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new DDataContext())
            {

                var lotNumDb = db.LotInformation.FirstOrDefault(r => r.lot_number.Equals(r.lot_number));

                 if (lotNumDb != null || lotNumDb.lot_number.ToString().Equals(lot.lot_number))
                 {
                     confirmationWindow.Message = LanguageResources.Resource.Sample_Exists_Already;
                     dialogService.ShowDialog(LanguageResources.Resource.Error, confirmationWindow);
                 }
                 else {

                     Console.WriteLine("lot does not exist. yay");

                 }


               DateTime ExpirationDate = lot.exp_date;
                if (ExpirationDate != null)
                {
                    if (DateTime.Compare(ExpirationDate, DateTime.Now) > 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {

                           LotInformation lotInfo = db.LotInformation.FirstOrDefault(r => r.lot_number.Equals(lotNumber));
                        }
                        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
                        {
                            //TODO: Add a Dialog Here
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ExpirationDate);
                        errorWindow.Message = LanguageResources.Resource.Lot_Expired;
                        dialogService.ShowDialog(LanguageResources.Resource.Error, errorWindow);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    errorWindow.Message = LanguageResources.Resource.Lot_Not_In_Database;
                    dialogService.ShowDialog(LanguageResources.Resource.Error, errorWindow);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            errorWindow.Message = LanguageResources.Resource.Database_Error;
            dialogService.ShowDialog(LanguageResources.Resource.Error, errorWindow);
            logger.writeErrLog(LanguageResources.Resource.Database_Error);
        }

    }
```

I think I'm just having problems with when to grab the lot_number in this process.

This part below gives me problems. It keeps showing the Sample Exists already message for unique lot numbers that I'm uploading and I'm not sure why. I think it's a problem with my LINQ query but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any ideas?

```
                var lotNumDb = db.LotInformation.FirstOrDefault(r => r.lot_number.Equals(r.lot_number));

                 if (lotNumDb != null || lotNumDb.lot_number.ToString().Equals(lot.lot_number))
                 {
                     confirmationWindow.Message = LanguageResources.Resource.Sample_Exists_Already;
                     dialogService.ShowDialog(LanguageResources.Resource.Error, confirmationWindow);
                 }
                 else {

                     Console.WriteLine("lot does not exist. yay");

                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't use like this:

```
db.LotInformation.FirstOrDefault(r => r.lot_number.Equals(r.lot_number))
```

may be :

```
 db.LotInformation.FirstOrDefault(r => r.lot_number.Equals(lot.lot_number))
```

or

```
 db.LotInformation.FirstOrDefault(r => r.lot_number.Equals(a string))
```

Comment: I know what's wrong... the first problem is if I have a new database and I check to see if the lot number is inside the database, it throws a null exception. Instead of a null exception being thrown, I just want it to detect that if the column is empty, then continue with binding. If existing, do not bind