# How can I update my DataGrid when a user makes a selection in the ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

Here's my ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="125,110,0,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="120"
          DisplayMemberPath="lot_number"
          ItemsSource="{Binding LotNumList}"
          RenderTransformOrigin="0.583,2" Height="18" />
```

Here's a DataGrid that I want to update the values to:

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="228,177,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Height="292" Width="617" ItemsSource="{Binding ComponentsList}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Component" Binding="{Binding component}" CanUserResize="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Control" Binding="{Binding aControl}" CanUserResize="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Reference" Binding="{Binding cal_ref}" CanUserResize="False" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Family" Binding="{Binding family}" CanUserResize="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding componentId }" CanUserResize="False"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Here's how I'm grabbing data from db to populate the ComboBox:

```
//Grabs the lot_number column from db that is distinct
var lotNum = db.LotInformation.GroupBy(i => i.lot_number)
                              .Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault());

//Loops through the lot numbers column in db and converts to list 
foreach (var item in lotNum)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.lot_number);
}
LotNumList = lotNum.ToList();
```

Now I am wondering how do I connect my ComboBox so that when I select a value in the ComboBox... then the DataGrid gets updated based on the value of the selection in the ComboBox.

I tried something like this:

```
private void UpdateExistLotList(string LotNumber)
{
    using (var db = new DDataContext())
    {
        //Grabs the lot_number column from db that is distinct
        var ExistLot = db.LotInformation.First(l => l.lot_number.Equals(LotNumber));
    }
}
```

Calling the method in my lot number list property but it doesn't get called or just doesn't work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Properties:

```
public List<Components> ComponentsList
    {
        get 
        {
           return components;
        }
        set
        {
            components = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ComponentsList");
        }

    }

public string LotNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return lotNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            lotNumber = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("LotNumber");
        }
    }

    public List<LotInformation> LotNumList
    {
        get
        {
            return lotNumList;
        }
        set
        {
            lotNumList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("LotNumList");
           UpdateExistLotList(LotNumber);

        }
    }
```

Here's where LotNumber is declared (I take the deserialized value of lot number from memory and assign it to LotNumber):

```
public void DeSerializationXML(string filePath)
    {
        XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
        xRoot.ElementName = "lot_information";
        xRoot.IsNullable = false;

        // Create an instance of lotinformation class.
        var lot = new LotInformation();

        // Create an instance of stream writer.
        TextReader txtReader = new StreamReader(filePath);

        // Create and instance of XmlSerializer class.
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LotInformation), xRoot);

        // DeSerialize from the StreamReader
        lot = (LotInformation)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(txtReader);

        // Close the stream reader
        txtReader.Close();

        //Storing deserialized strings to db
        using (var db = new DMIDataContext())
        {


            LotInformation newLot = new LotInformation();


            if (newLot != null)
            {
                newLot.Id = lot.Id;
                newLot.lot_number = lot.lot_number;
                newLot.exp_date = lot.exp_date;

                LotNumber = newLot.lot_number;
                ExpirationDate = newLot.exp_date.ToString();

                //Grabs the lot_number column from db that is distinct
                var lotNum = db.LotInformation.GroupBy(i => i.lot_number).Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault());

                //Loops through the lot numbers column in db and converts to list 
                foreach (var item in lotNum)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.lot_number);
                }
                LotNumList = lotNum.ToList();

                foreach (Components comp in lot.Components)
                {
                    newLot.Components.Add(comp);

                }
                ComponentsList = newLot.Components;

                foreach (Families fam in lot.Families)
                {

                    newLot.Families.Add(fam);
                }
                FamiliesList = newLot.Families;

                try
                {
                    db.LotInformation.Add(newLot);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    Console.WriteLine("successfully");
                }
                catch
                {
                    //TODO: Add a Dialog Here

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: @Grant Winney, Updated post. I called UpdateExistLostList in my List<LotInformation> LotNumList property. LotNumber is the lot number that was deserialized and stored in memory. I apologize if the post is messy, I kept changing parameters and I might have junk code :/ Please let me know if you have any more questions. Thank you.

Comment: @Rang, Hi, I will edit my post and then you guys can see my messy code. Please let me know if you have any further questions. I'm sorry about the 50 rep thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void UpdateExistLotList()
{
    using (var db = new DDataContext())
    {
        //Grabs the lot_number column from db that is distinct
        var ExistLot = db.LotInformation.First(l => l.lot_number.Equals(LotNumber));
    }
}
```

This method has no para?

But you call it like this?

```
{
    lotNumList = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged("LotNumList");
    UpdateExistLotList(LotNumber);

}
```

Is there something wrong?

Your question is that `UpdateExistLotList` was never called?

Try to add a breakpoint on `RaisePropertyChanged("LotNumList");` in VisualStudio and observe why it doesn't get called.

In your code, I don't know the use of `ExistLot` and `LotNumber`.

I guess your demand is like this?

Comobox shows LotInformation, select one LotInformation and make datagrid shows LotInformation.Components ?

If so,you can Binding DataGrid's `Itemsource={Binding Components,ElementName=ComboboxName}`
or you can Binding Combobox's SelectedItem/SelectedValue, and then set ComponentsList in these events.

---

Get your demand.

You means you don't set a relationship between Components and LotInformation in EntityFramework or other DB framework.
If you use EF, I advise you make a relationship between Components and LotInformation,and then you can get ComponentsList by `LotInformation.Components`.

In another way, try like this:

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="125,110,0,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="120"
          DisplayMemberPath="lot_number"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLot}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding LotNumList}"
          RenderTransformOrigin="0.583,2" Height="18" />


     private LotInformation selectedLot;

    public LotInformation SelectedLot
    {
        get { return selectedLot; }
        set
        {
            selectedLot = value;
            var lot = value as LotInformation;
            if (lot != null)
            {
                ComponentsList = new List<Components>();
                //add ComponentsList 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually sorry, UpdateExistLotList should have string LotNumber as parameter. So UpdateExistLotList(string LotNumber). The lotnumber parameter in the debugger works and it's fine. Just the binding between the combobox and the datagrid doesnt' work.

Comment: ComboBox only shows lot_number column from db which is associated with the LotInformation table. The thing is, I want to pull data from other tables that have the foreign key to the primary key of the lot number table.

Comment: Another thing is, if what I'm doing above is too confusing, that's okay. Is it possible for you to provide a simple example of how to update DataGrid after selecting an item in a ComboBox? I can follow along a simple example. Thanks again!

Comment: I will test it, btw, I am getting a "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection." exception thrown for foreach... loop. I'm guessing I just need to set my db context? I'll check github, thanks for your help! :D

Comment: Yes,it is wrong.Because add/remove in foreach will change the source.I just provide a way.You can set ComponentsList by your own way.

Comment: Thanks!! I believe I got it working alright... least for now :D Btw, I have another question if you want to answer it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434823/wpf-how-do-i-validate-that-a-number-from-memory-is-not-duplicated-in-db-table